# Regex: Match White Space & New Lines Until Specific Character

Tags: regex, macros, textmate

I'm trying to write a macro for Textmate to take a few lines of code and turn them into one css line. So:

```
#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto;
text-align: colorenter;
width: 700px;}
```

would become

```
#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto;text-align: colorenter;width: 700px;}
```

so basically I need to match new lines and white space and turn them into just a single space UNTIL it hits `}` that's where it ends. I don't want to go over the entire css file just the one block.

I'm really bad at regex any help would be GREATLY appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Look for the pattern:

```
\s+(?=[^{}]*})
```

and replace it with a single space.

`\s+` matches one or more white space characters (space, tab, line-break) only when looking ahead a `}` can be seen without encountering a `{` between it.

Beware that this will go wrong in cases like this:

```css
#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto;
text-align: colorenter;              /*    }     */
width: 700px;}
```

A little PHP demo:

```
<?php
$css = '#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto;



text-align: colorenter;



width: 700px;}

#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto;
text-align: colorenter;
width: 700px;}';

echo preg_replace('/\s+(?=[^{}]*})/', ' ', $css);
?>
```

will print:

```
#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto; text-align: colorenter; width: 700px;}

#rules #footer ul { margin: 0 auto; text-align: colorenter; width: 700px;}
```

as you can see on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/I88Qo).

Comment: Just a note for the OP that this will not work with selectors spread over several lines.

Comment: That seems to be working.. however is it possible to structure it in a way that if I keep replacing the found text with a space... in a loop eventually it will get to a place where there is no more NEW LINES before the closing } ... now when this happens it shouldn't find any more new lines... I want it to be contained to one { block } ... so is it possible to do a check that if there is no NEW LINES before the closing bracket don't find anything? I need to run this as one key stroke macro that will take multiple lines of css and turn it into one line... one block at a time, thanks Bart

Comment: @Bart, I am not sure what you mean. Perhaps you could edit your original question with this new requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If your tool supports later versions of PCRE or the like, and you want this to remove line breaks from selectors as well, then you could use a regex like

`(?:\S(?<!})|^)[ \t]*\K[\n\r]\s*`
replaced by a space.

I wrote this to only remove line breaks and white space at the beginning of lines. You could use an equivalent of `s/(\s)\s+/$1/g` to remove all double spaces in other places too.

Perl demo:

```
perl -E "$_=qq'foo,\noof {\n\tbar /* } */\n\tbaz\n}\nfoo{\nbaz\n}';say;s/(?:\S(?<!})|^)[ \t]*\K[\n\r]\s*/ /g;say"
```

Input:

```
foo,
oof {
        bar /* } */
        baz
}
foo{
baz
}
```

Result:

```
foo, oof { bar /* } */ baz }
foo{ baz }
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work... I'm getting no matches... supposedly textmate uses Oniguruma regular expression library. I'm guessing the syntax is different? Here is more info http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions

Comment: @Bart: As I said, that only works with recent PCRE/Perl or compatible version. The regex engine needs to support `\K` for this to work, which I didn't find in the docs you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a much simpler solution. Just make a macro that replaces newlines with spaces. You'd have to only run it on selections, but I think that's all you wanted in the first place.